# Struct with array of structs JNA

Tags: java, c++, arrays, struct, jna

I have following C++ structs and functions:

```
typedef struct _Phase_Information
{
  char infoMessage[MAX];
} INFORMATION;

typedef struct _Informations
{
  int infoCount;
  INFORMATION *infoArray;
} INFORMATIONS ;

int GetInformations(INFORMATIONS *pInfos);
```

I use them like this:

```
INFORMATIONS informations;
INFORMATION * informationArray = new INFORMATION[MAX_INFOS];
informations.info = informationArray;
int error = GetInformations(&informations);
```

Now I want to use my C++ library in Java by using JNA ... so I did the following:

```
public class Information extends Structure {
  public char[] infoMessage = new char[MAX];
  public Information () { super(); }
  protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("infoMessage ");
  }
  public Information (char infoMessage []) {
    super();
    if ((infoMessage .length != this.infoMessage .length)) 
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong array size !");
    this.infoMessage  = infoMessage ;
  }

  public static class ByReference extends Information implements Structure.ByReference {};
  public static class ByValue extends Information implements Structure.ByValue {};
}

public class Informations extends Structure {
  public int infoCount;
  public Information.ByReference infoArray;
  public Informations () { super(); }
  protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("infoCount", "infoArray");
  }
  public Informations(int infoCount, Information.ByReference infoArray) {
    super();
    this.infoCount= infoCount;
    this.infoArray= infoArray;
  }
  public static class ByReference extends Informations implements Structure.ByReference {};
  public static class ByValue extends Informations implements Structure.ByValue {};
}
```

I tried to call the library like this:

```
Informations.ByReference informations = new Informations.ByReference();
informations.infoArray= new Information.ByReference();
int error = CLib.GetInformations(Informations);

Information[] test =(Information[])informations.infoArray.toArray(Informations.infoCount);
```

Some times I only retrieve the first element of the array but the rest of the time my Java crashes ... so I believe it is related to not allocating memory on the java site but I cannot get any further :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native `char` corresponds to Java `byte`.

Note that your example is passing an array of size one to `GetInformations`.

Aside from that incorrect mapping, which may very well be the cause of your crash, your mapping looks OK.

**EDIT**

You should initialize the `infoCount` to the size of the array you're passing in ("1" in your example).  If you want to pass in a larger array, you'll need to call `.toArray()` on `informations.infoArray` *prior* to calling `GetInformations()`.  Memory for additional array elements is allocated when you call `Structure.toArray()`; until then you only have memory allocated for a single element.

Comment: Calling toArray() fixes the problem with the java crashes but I don't know the size of the array before calling the function but I think that is nothing we must discuss at this point. Thank you! :)